# Geoserver/Image Mosaic - A problem when adding multiple Custom Dimensions

Tags: geoserver

I want to add more custom dimensions. My `indexer.properties` file is:

```
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
ElevationAttribute=elevation
AdditionalDomainAttributes=indeksi(indeksi)
AdditionalDomainAttributes=parcela(parcela)
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Integer,parcela:Integer,indeksi:String
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion),IntegerFileNameExtractorSPI[elevationregex](elevation),IntegerFileNameExtractorSPI[parcelaregex](parcela),StringFileNameExtractorSPI[indeksiregex](indeksi)
```

Only one custom dimension (PARCELA) appears in the GUI Geoserver and should be two (PARCELA and INDEKSI)

[image]

The database (Postgresql) correctly creates all attributes and values

[image]

Any ideas what the problem is? Why is the GUI GeoServer not appear both custom dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each variable in the `indexer.properties` file can only be set once. The second "AdditionalDomainAttributes" overwrites the first one.

You need to put the attributes comma-separated like this:

```
AdditionalDomainAttributes=indeksi(indeksi),parcela(parcela)
```