# Using a PostGIS raster catalog in GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, image-mosaic, raster-catalog

I have a PostGIS table cataloging 10,000+ GeoTIFFs. Each table row has a name, file path, and a polygon as the bounding box. The rasters are spread out all over the globe, they are not adjacent.

I would like to be able to search them, and add them to my map one at a time.

I thought about using imageMosaic, and including the name attribute in "AdditionalDomainAttributes" in my indexer.properties file like I saw in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/258421/139791), but I don't need them as a mosaic as I never need to serve more than one or two at a time, and imageMosaic doesn't seem allow rasters to be added that  not adjacent or overlapping to existing ones. (Also this database is added to frequently.)

Is there a different plugin I should use, or a way to handle this effectively? The best I have come up with so far is just using image mosaic, and creating a global "background" raster so that they are all overlapping, and then just only allowing my client to request one "name" at a time when requesting tiles for that layer.

I'm using GeoServer 2.15.0

Comment: what makes you think "imageMosaic doesn't seem allow rasters to be added that not adjacent or overlapping to existing ones"?

Comment: Glad to know that the ImageMosaic is the tool to use. It turned out that my images had different meta-data, even though they had the same srs. Using GDAL I was able to get them to have the same meta-data, and then the images worked together.